# How to update existing CMS block content using data patches?

Tags: patches, magento2.3.3, cms-block, patch-data

I have updated content for the existing cms page by using data patches in Magento 2.3.3, but the same approach not working for CMS block.

```
<?php

namespace Test\CmsExport\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory;

class UpdateTest2Block implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface {

  private $blockFactory;
  private $moduleDataSetup;

  public function __construct(
        PageFactory $blockFactory,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

  public function apply () {

      $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
      $test2BlockContent = '<p>Test 2 block updated using data patches</p>';

      $test2Block = $this->createBlock()->load(
                  'test2',
                  'identifier'
              );
      $test2BlockId = $test2Block->getId();
        if ($test2BlockId) {
          $test2Block->setContent($test2BlockContent);
            $test2Block->save();
        }
      $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }
    public static function getDependencies() {
        return [];
    }
    public static function getVersion() {
        return '1.0.1';
    }
    public function getAliases() {
        return [];
    }
    private function createBlock() {
        return $this->blockFactory->create();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way...

```
<?php

namespace Test\CmsExport\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory;
/**
 * Class UpdateTest2Block 
 * @package Test\CmsExport\Setup\Patch\Data
 */
class UpdateTest2Block implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var BlockFactory
     */
    private $blockFactory;

    /**
     * AddAccessViolationPageAndAssignB2CCustomers constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param PageFactory $blockFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        BlockFactory $blockFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $newCmsStaticBlock = [
            'title' => 'Terms & Conditions',
            'identifier' => 'terms-conditions',
            'content' => '<div class="cms-terms">CMS Static Block Content goes here</div>',
            'is_active' => 1,
            'stores' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
        ];

        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
        $block = $this->blockFactory->create();
        $block->setData($newCmsStaticBlock)->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getVersion()
    {
        return '2.0.0';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Found the issue in that file and fixed it. Thanks